# Using PHP 5.3 namespaces (Doctrine2) with Zend Framework classes

Tags: php, namespaces

i am having a situation where my doctrine model, `Post`, is in the namespace `Application\Entities` and i want to try to implement `Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface`. i get the error

> Fatal error: Interface
>   'Application\Entities\Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface'
>   not found in
>   D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFram
>   ework\LearningZF\library\Application\Entities\Post.php
>   on line 8

```
namespace Application\Entities;
use DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet\Node;

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="posts")
 */
class Post implements Node, Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface {
```

## update

if i try

```
class Post implements Node, \Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface {
```

> Fatal error: Interface
>   'Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface' not
>   found in
>   D:\Projects\Websites\php\ZendFramework\LearningZF\library\Application\Entities\Post.php on
>   line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [the ZF 2.0 branch](http://git.zendframework.com/?a=summary&p=zf) or the stable one, e.g. 1.10? Is your autoloader setup to load classes with the ZF naming scheme?

You can use the Conversion tool the ZF devs used to convert ZF to using namespaces:

- http://github.com/ralphschindler/PHPTools
- http://blog.calevans.com/2010/03/27/zends-new-namespace-converter/

Comment: i am using ZF1.10. oh but 2.0 is out, i know its in development, but i guess theres not docs to help me get started? isit ... erm ... usable at least for me to start learning it? or isit giving errors everywhere? i'll check out the links tho

Comment: @jiewmeng it's not officially out. Just like Doctrine is still in beta.

Comment: Doctrine works great so far for me :) ok back to the tool. i created the php 5.3 namespaced ZF1.10. i want to start using it. i guess all i have to do is convert all PEAR namespaces to real namespaces. in the process of conversion, i was looking up `Zend_Controller_Plugin_ErrorHandler` in the mapping xml but cant find it ...

Comment: ... i see that alot of paths are invalid? cos things like `Zend/Application.php` becomes `Zend/Application/Application.php`?

Comment: @jiewmeng In [ZF2.0, this is where the file is supposed to be then](http://git.zendframework.com/?a=tree&p=zf&h=586e61be767fe39f69b656371a7ecd1f12b2b664&hb=97335edd11196b4e6e6de599fdc4dd0260a5f4b9&f=library/Zend/Application). Cant help much with the tool though. havent used it. Just remembered it's public.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember Zend Framework does not uses namespaces (until 2.x comes out anyway) so it's classes are in global namespace. Try `class Post implements Node, \Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface {`

Comment: i tried that but got 'Interface 'Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface' not found ' strange see my update ...

Answer (score 0):

i am going to put this as an answer, so i can mark this qn as answered if noone have any other answers, its actually a workaround i used. i am not too sure why it worked exactly, or rather why the Zend autoloader failed

i added the `require_once` to include `Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface`

```
namespace Application\Entities;
use DoctrineExtensions\NestedSet\Node;
require_once "Zend/Acl/Resource/Interface.php";

/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="posts")
 */
class Post implements Node, \Zend_Acl_Resource_Interface {
```

i think a better fix will be to conversion tool in [@Gordon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353847/using-php-5-3-namespaces-doctrine2-with-zend-framework-classes/3354003#3354003). but i cant fix all the errors i get with "unclean" conversion yet. paths are broken.